# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to use a plugin in my template but for some reason it doesn’t work.

here is my code:

```
import Vue from 'Vue';
import vueSmoothScroll from 'vue-smooth-scroll';

Vue.use(vueSmoothScroll);

export default {
 name: 'home-view',
 components: {
 },
layout: 'default',
mixins: [
 PageHeaderFromContentData,
 vueSmoothScroll,
],
data() {
 return {
  openLayer: null,
 };
},
methods: {
 },
};
```

And here is my template:

```
<a v-smooth-scroll href="#startpage-possibilities">anchor</a>
<div id="startpage-possibilities">###</div>
```

Thats the plugin I want to use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-smooth-scroll